# Vue3 Errorhandling in Vuex , how to catch error, when you indirectly dispatch a naction?

Tags: error-handling, vuex, vuejs3

auth(){} is to send request to the server. For, authentication ,login and signUp url is different. So I use two actions to assign the url by mode "login/signUp". then "login" and "signUp" will dispatch auth(){}

In the past, I directly put send request function fetch () in login() / signUp(). when error throw out ,I can catch it by use try {} catch{}.

Now, I want to reduct the duplicated code . The problem is , the error will be throw out by auth(), in Vue3 component, what I dispatch is not auth(), it is login() / signUp().

How can I get the error? will it be possible to pass the error through login()/signUp(),then I can get it ?

[image: an bridge actions blocks me to get error]

---

updated:
auth.vue

```
    async setUser() {
      if (this.mode === "sign up") {
        if (this.emailIsValid === true && this.passwordsIsValid === true) {
          const payload = {
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password,
          };
          await this.$store.dispatch("homepage/signUp", payload);
        }
      } else if (this.mode === "login") {
        if (this.emailIsValid === true && this.passwordsIsValid === true) {
          this.isLoading = true;
          const payload = {
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password,
          };
          try {
            await this.$store.dispatch("homepage/login", payload);
          } catch (err) {
            this.isLoading = false;
            // console.log(err);
            this.error = err.message || "something went wrong";
          }
         
        }
      }
    },
```

Vuex actions.js

```
 async signUp (context, payload) {
    context.dispatch('auth', {
      ...payload,
      mode: 'sign up'
    })
  },
  async login (context, payload) {
  await context.dispatch('auth', {
      ...payload,
      mode: 'login'
    })
  },
  async auth (context, payload) {
    let url = ''

    if (payload.mode === 'sign up') {
      url =
        'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[api key]'
    } else if (payload.mode === 'login') {
      url =
        'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[api key]'
    }

    const res = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: payload.email,
        password: payload.password,
        returnSecureToken: true
      })
    })

    const resData = await res.json()

    if (!res.ok) {
      // console.log(resData)
      const error = new Error(resData.error.message || 'Try again later ')
      throw error
    }   
    }
  }
```

Comment: provide code of your vuex action please

Answer (score 0):

just pass error the bridge action .
add another try{} catch {}

vuex actions.js

```
 async login (context, payload) {
    try {
      await context.dispatch('auth', {
        ...payload,
        mode: 'login'

      })
    } catch (err) {

      throw err
    }
  }
```